# How to calculate cooling time for copper billet after forging operation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, cooling

Presently we are heating copper billet to 740 deg. celsius and forging it in a Hydraulic press. Temperature after forging is noted at 700 deg. celsius. Room temperature is noted at 15 deg. celsius. How long will it take for the copper billet to cool down to room temperature?

Billet thickness: 50 mm
surface area: 0.01 m2

what formula to use?

Answer (score 0):

You shall most probably use Newton's formula:
$$\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{hS}{c}(T-T_{\mathrm{ext}})$$

Where $T$ is the temperature of the object, $T_{\mathrm{ext}}$ the room temperature, $S$ its surface area, $c$ its heat capacity of your object, and $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient. This latter is certainly the hardest to estimate theoretically, you shall fit it with some measurement in the situation you describe

Comment: It is worth noting that the other formulas like the Stefan-Boltzman blackbody radiation law likely are irrelevant because the temperature is not that high, but this is something one should check by calculating the energy loss and comparing with Newton... still, the empirical measurement will be far more important and might even show other complications (some materials have non-trivial phase changes affecting cooling curves).